# Why collection initializer is not working together with expression body property?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I think it's best to show the code right now:

```
class Foo
{
    public ICollection<int> Ints1 { get; } = new List<int>();

    public ICollection<int> Ints2 => new List<int>();
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo
        {
            Ints1 = { 1, 2, 3 },
            Ints2 = { 4, 5, 6 }
        };

        foreach (var i in foo.Ints1)
            Console.WriteLine(i);

        foreach (var i in foo.Ints2)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Obviously the `Main` method should print 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, but it prints 1, 2, 3 only. After initialization `foo.Ints2.Count` is equals to zero. Why?

Comment: Your `Ints2` create new `List` on every access.

Comment: @PetSerAl, I grok, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of how you have defined the property Int2. While it is indeed a getter, it's is always returning a new list. Int1 is a read only auto property so it's always returning the same list. Equivalent compiler magic code removed for class Foo below:

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly ICollection<int> ints1 = new List<int>(); 
    public ICollection<int> Ints1 { get { return this.ints1; } }

    public ICollection<int> Ints2 { get { return new List<int>(); } }
}
```

As you can see, all mututations to Ints2 are lost because the list is always new.

Answer (score 2):

`Ints2 => new List<int>();` is short for `Ints2 { get { return new List<int>(); } }`. It returns a new empty list each time the property is read. You already have the fix: your first form stores the list in a field.

Answer (score 2):

Each time when you access your `Ints2` property it returns new `List<int>` instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ICollection<int> Ints1 { get; } = new List<int>();
```

This line means that the backing field returned by the property is initialized with `new List<int>()`.

What Collection initializer do is call `Add` method for each element, so `Ints1` will have 3 elements (`1`, `2`, `3`).

---

```
public ICollection<int> Ints2 => new List<int>();
```

Expression bodied means that you are defining the body of the `getter`, something like this:

```
public ICollection<int> Ints2 => new List<int>();
{
    get 
    {
        return new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Each time you call `Ints2` an new instance is returned, thats why `Count` property returns `0`.